# Travis and .tar: unrecognized option '--exclude-vcs-ignores'

Tags: travis-ci, tar

I am trying to use `heroku builds:create -a app-name` to deploy my app to Heroku but that command triggers the creation of a tarball with the `--exclude-vcs-ignores` flag which is probably not supported by Travis.

Is there any way around that? Thanks